# How to fix no internet when using a USB network adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I'm very new to Linux, so please point anything out if I get it wrong. About 1 year ago, I built a PC and ran only windows on it. I purchased a USB Wi-fi adapter which supported Windows and *apparently* Ubuntu. But recently I tried to get into Linux, only for the Wi-Fi adapter to not work with Linux. If anyone wants to know, lsusb labels it as "Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac WLAN Adapter" and the model name is "Edup EP-AC1687" Any help would be greatly appreciated. Edit: whenever I try to run the driver installer, it says "bash: make: command not found"

Comment: What are the Vendor ID and Product ID?

Comment: INclude the full output of `lsusb` for us - there will be device/vendor IDs attached and we can determine *which* device you're actually using, then we can give you a solution to install the adapter drivers (if needed)

Comment: Providing details as to what Ubuntu you are using may also be useful, is it a desktop release? server? other? and which release?  Being as specific as you can helps us to better respond to you.

Comment: Check the manufacturer website to see if they provide a linux driver for your adapter model. Simple as that.

Comment: "*bash: make: command not found*" means that you don't have the `build-essential` package installed. It contains the compiler needed to build your kernel module (driver). If you have no other method of online access, then you have a classic chicken-and-egg problem. The easiest solution is often to borrow a friend's USB WiFi dongle for the afternoon. Different manufacturers have varying levels of Linux support. My opinion is that your vendor's claim of Linux compatibility is deceptive and fraudulent: Building your own drivers went out of style 20 years ago, and is considered unacceptable today.

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](https://www.szedup.com/support/driver-download/ep-ac1687-driver/) is the software you need. Second to last in the 1st menu. Download and install...

If it comes as a .deb file you will need to use `dpkg -i xxxxx.deb`  Replace xxxxx with file name. run command from inside same directory as the file...

Comment: It comes as a .zip file?

Answer (score 0):

"it says "bash: make: command not found""

Your installer tries to run the command "make" but cant find it. Try to run sudo apt install make in order to install make before trying to run the installer again.

There might be other prerequisites before everything will compile but with a little bit of research you should be able to install them using "apt install" to.